# jQuery Draggable with Zoom on Element instead of Container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zooming, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a similiar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930092/jquery-draggable-with-zoom-problem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605439/jquery-draggable-div-with-zoom), the difference is that the zoom is on the draggable element and not on the container. I copied the jsFiddle provided on the second question mentioned above and changed the zoom property from the container to the element. You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Zzu/2/) and the code is:

HTML

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="dragme"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#canvas {
   width:500px;
   height:250px;
   border:1px solid #444;
}
#dragme {
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   background:#f30;
   zoom:0.9;
}
```

JS

```
$('#dragme').draggable();
```

I tried to understand what's the problem but it seems every changes I try never work. The main problems are:

- When I start dragging, the element moves up and to the left slightly;
- The container boundaries are being incorrectly calculated;

Can you understand what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is absolutely not necessary, remove zoom from css. It does not play good with Jquery draggable. Check here for more info [Jquery draggable with zoom problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930092/jquery-draggable-with-zoom-problem?rq=1)

Then if you want to drag within canvas just add

```
containment: "parent"
```