# Draggable element smart guides not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have been looking for smart guides for draggable elements and found one nice script here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22062111

It is working perfectly until I changed the structure a bit.
Guides are not showing correctly if wrapper is aligned display:inline-block or float:left

I have created a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/A6CpP/110/

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "smartguides", {
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var i = $(this).data("draggable");
    console.log(i);
    var o = i.options;
        i.elements = [];
        $(o.smartguides.constructor != String ? ( o.smartguides.items || ':data(draggable)' ) : o.smartguides).each(function() {
            var $t = $(this); var $o = $t.offset();
            if(this != i.element[0]) i.elements.push({
                item: this,
                width: $t.outerWidth(), height: $t.outerHeight(),
                top: $o.top, left: $o.left
            });
        });
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(".objectx").css({"display":"none"});
        $(".objecty").css({"display":"none"});
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var inst = $(this).data("draggable"), o = inst.options;
        var d = o.tolerance;
        $(".objectx").css({"display":"none"});
        $(".objecty").css({"display":"none"});
            var x1 = ui.offset.left, x2 = x1 + inst.helperProportions.width,
                y1 = ui.offset.top, y2 = y1 + inst.helperProportions.height,
                xc = (x1 + x2) / 2, yc = (y1 + y2) / 2;
            for (var i = inst.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                var l = inst.elements[i].left, r = l + inst.elements[i].width,
                    t = inst.elements[i].top, b = t + inst.elements[i].height,
                    hc = (l + r) / 2, vc = (t + b) / 2;
                    var ls = Math.abs(l - x2) <= d;
                    var rs = Math.abs(r - x1) <= d;
                    var ts = Math.abs(t - y2) <= d;
                    var bs = Math.abs(b - y1) <= d;
                    var hs = Math.abs(hc - xc) <= d;
                    var vs = Math.abs(vc - yc) <= d; 
                if(ls) {
                    ui.position.left = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", { top: 0, left: l - inst.helperProportions.width }).left - inst.margins.left;
                    $(".objectx").css({"left":l-d-4,"display":"block"});
                }
                if(rs) {
                    ui.position.left = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", { top: 0, left: r }).left - inst.margins.left;
                     $(".objectx").css({"left":r-d-4,"display":"block"});
                }

                if(ts) {
                    ui.position.top = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", { top: t - inst.helperProportions.height, left: 0 }).top - inst.margins.top;
                    $(".objecty").css({"top":t-d-4,"display":"block"});
                }
                if(bs) {
                    ui.position.top = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", { top: b, left: 0 }).top - inst.margins.top;
                    $(".objecty").css({"top":b-d-4,"display":"block"});
                }
                if(hs) {
                    ui.position.left = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", { top: 0, left: hc - inst.helperProportions.width/2 }).left - inst.margins.left;
                     $(".objectx").css({"left":hc-d-4,"display":"block"});
                }
                if(vs) {
                    ui.position.top = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", { top: vc - inst.helperProportions.height/2, left: 0 }).top - inst.margins.top;
                    $(".objecty").css({"top":vc-d-4,"display":"block"});
                }


            };
        }
});
$('.other-objects').draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    smartguides:".other-objects",
    tolerance:5
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try another plugin. I added smart guides functionality to draggable and resizable plugins.

```
$('.drag')
    .draggable({
        smartGuides: '.drag:not(".selected")'
    })
    .resizable({
        handles: 'all',
        smartGuides: '.drag:not(".selected")'
    }
```

You can see how it works:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/bypr7Lt3/2/

github: https://github.com/aichukanov/smartguides

demo-site: https://ready2.net/smartguides.shtml