# resizable jquery plugin zoom issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm creating a form wysiwyg builder and I'm having problems with the resizable jquery plugin. It seems that when I resize any item that is on the page the zoom goes out of whack. I have found a workaround for draggable here: [Jquery draggable with zoom problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930092/jquery-draggable-with-zoom-problem)

But I cannot find the same workaround for resizable. 
The scenario is when I create a resizable and draggable item and I zoom in or out the item seems to drift outside of its containing parent. You can see this 
here:
http://drniermanoptometry.cu.cc/Main/Forms_Module/editForm.php/?name=horizontal-clickersearch.html
Note: click the allocation 'NO' button to create a resizable draggable item. And then zoom out using control++

I have set the containment to parent and the css position to relative to no avail.

There are a few other issues with resizable. When I resize the item it does not let me drag the item all the way to the right and draggable does not work in FF. Possibly related?
**Update:**
I have found out that there is a problem with margins set to auto so I have the left side of my resizeable container fixed to avoid the issue. But I still would like to know if there is a workaround for auto margins.
This guy has the same issue... http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?236987-jQuery-resizable-with-margin-0-auto

Code Below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.create').click(function(){
                var jquerybox = $('<div/>' , {class: 'blocked form-item' , width: '100px', height: '20px' , background: 'red'} );
                var zoom = $('#form-preview').css('zoom');
                var canvasHeight = $('#form-preview').height();
                var canvasWidth = $('#form-preview').width();
                jquerybox.resizable({
                    containment: 'parent'
                });

                jquerybox.draggable({
                    containment: 'parent',
                    drag: function(evt,ui)
                    {
                        // zoom fix
                        ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
                        ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);

                        // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
                        if (ui.position.left < 0) 
                            ui.position.left = 0;
                        if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth)
                            ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();  
                        if (ui.position.top < 0)
                            ui.position.top = 0;
                        if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight)
                            ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();  

                    }                 
                });
                $('#form-preview').append(jquerybox);
        }); 
    });
    function updateItem(Item){
        //ajax call to update script
        }
</script>

<style>
.blocked{
    display:block;
    background: red;}
#form-preview{
    height: 550px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
.centered{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id = "editbar">
<form action="Idkyet" method = "POST">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Allocated</th>
</tr>
<?

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){
        require_once '../../db_connect.php';
        $sqlpre = 'SELECT id FROM forms WHERE name = "' . $_GET['name'] . '";';
        $res = $mysqli->query($sqlpre);
        $rds = $res->fetch_array();
        $id = $rds['id'];
        $res->free();

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM form_fields WHERE form_id = ' . $id ;
        $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if($res){
            while($rds = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><input value = " ' .  $rds['type'] . ' "type="textarea"></td>';
                echo '<td><input class = "create centered" type="button" value = ' . (($rds['allocated'] == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'NO') . '></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</table>
</form>
<div id = "form-preview">
    <div class = "blocked"height = "20px"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @jimbo, I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285420/jquery-ui-resize-objects-when-content-is-zoomed-via-css/27383025)

Comment: Use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212683/jquery-drag-resize-with-css-transform-scale