# CSS Zoom interfering with jQuery scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a Website that, on Mobile Browsers, zooms out, as it's a fixed width website. Instead of using the viewport meta tags I've taken to the following:

```
html, body {
    zoom: 0.8;
}
```

This works great, but the problem is with my jQuery. I'm using simple jQuery code for a one-page website smooth scrolling, shown below:

```
/* Start Navigation */
jQuery('nav ul.menu li').click(function(e) {
    if(!scrollingAnim) {
        var page = jQuery(this).attr('data-page');

        updateMenu(page);

        scrollingAnim = true;

        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: (jQuery(page).offset().top - 70)
        }, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            scrollingAnim = false;
        });
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
/* End Navigation */
```

This used to work fine, but for obvious reasons will not work with my zoom. I've tried multiplying it by the zoom level, but it doesn't work. Is there anything you'd suggest?

Comment: Maybe your `scrollingAnim` was not defined, `var scrollingAnim;`. Have you checked for errors? I also don't get why you need to use both `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;`.

Comment: Got a demo? It'd make problem solving a lot easier

Comment: offset().top is changing with the change of the window scroll, which is just wrong. I don't know how we can solve this, except for returning window scroll to 0 and then ask for offset().top again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced with similar problem related to zoom and `offset().Top`. Tried to play with values in JS console and found this formula:

```
var scrollTopAnimateTo = ($(anchor).offset().top - $(".header").height()) * zoom + $(window).scrollTop() * (1 - zoom);
```

where `zoom < 1`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's .offset().top is changing with the change of the window scroll when you have CSS zoom involved...

Take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21048208/1090395
Hope it helps