# Bootstrap Scrollspy - not working properly with zoom or transform

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, offset, smoothing, scrollspy

I have a sticky menu which needs to be always in the top and page has several sections. And the menu is for single page section wise navigation. I used Bootstrap 4 scrollspy to achieve that but the problem is in windows laptop which has low resolution of 1275px, so i need to use either

html{ zoom: 0.75} or html {transform : scale(0.75)} . it made the look same like high resolution monitors,

Now the problem is with scrollspy that it could not identify the offset correctly, so active button in the navigation for that particular section is not correctly active.  Also when i press the menu button it goes to the section but with some jerking animation.

To replicate the issue:

For example : [`enter link description here`](https://codepen.io/latifur/pen/qLKXpj)
Issue replication : add this code in the css  html{zoom:0.75} and execute

Please help me on this

Comment: Can you post enough of your code using the snippet function [<>] to see the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I could not share the code and the link because it is deployed internally in the corporate environment, i could find some example in codepen and replicate the issue.

Comment: For example : https://codepen.io/latifur/pen/qLKXpj

Comment: Issue replication : add this code in the css html{zoom:0.75} and execute

Comment: For reference, the Scrollspy plugin you’re using has similar functionality to Bootstrap-4 scrollspy, but it’s a different plugin. You’re using [r3plica’s Scrollspy](https://github.com/r3plica/Scrollspy). Neither plugin works with `zoom: 75%` or `transform: scale(0.75).` This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698182/1011984 explains the problem. If all you’re doing is testing, then Ctrl-minus key may be enough. Trying to modify replica’s plugin would be a little bit of work.

Comment: FYI, I am using bootstrap 4 scrollspy only, but for  reference i showed the codepen example, but i get the same problem with bootstrap 4 scrollspy also. The problem is i need to use zoom:0.75 for windows low resolution laptops since i developed the website for high resolution monitors , do u suggest any alternate solution ?

Comment: One of my sites uses Bootstrap 4’s scrollspy and I did try zoom and scale on that site – both had the same problems you’re describing. While you could try to modify Bootstrap’s JavaScript, it might be easier and better to redesign your page to work with screens that have less pixel densities. Making the fonts smaller will make it difficult to read.